# Как передать в конвертор значение переменной?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, variable

У меня в таблице (WPF DataGrid) строки в зависимости от ряда условий должны иметь свойство IsEnabled True или False. Для анализа условий написал простенький мультиконвертор:

```
class DisRowConv : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values == null) 
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            else
            {
                DateTime? AvWorkDateID = values[0] as DateTime?;
                DateTime? AvElCom = values[1] as DateTime?;

                if ((AvWorkDateID == null || AvWorkDateID == avWorkDateID) && AvElCom == null)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Переменные **AvWorkDateID**, **AvElCom** это поля из БД SQL. Но для анализа необходимо использовать и внешнюю по отношению к конвертеру переменную **avWorkDateID**, ее я передаю используя DataContext.

```
public class AvWorkDateToXaml
    {
        public DateTime AvWorkDate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class BadCanals : Window
    {
        public AvWorkDateToXaml DateToXaml { get; set; }
        DateTime avWorkDateID; // Код нарушения

        public BadCanals(bool AddForm, DataAvZVKDataContext ref_ref, DateTime avWorkDateID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AddForm = AddForm;
            this.ref_ref = ref_ref;
            this.avWorkDateID = avWorkDateID;

            DateToXaml = new AvWorkDateToXaml() { AvWorkDate = avWorkDateID };
            this.DataContext = DateToXaml;
        }
}
```

XAML разметка:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="canalDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource canalViewSource}}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource disRowConv}">
                                                <Binding Path="AvWorkDateID"/>
                                                <Binding Path="AvElCom"/>
                                                <Binding Path="AvWorkDate"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Не понимаю, почему в конвертер передаются все три значения как Null. В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Это константа или она может меняться по ходу работы?

Comment: Это переменная и ее значение меняется по ходу работы.

Comment: Значит передавайте ее в конвертер третьим параметром

Comment: Не получается, см. картинку.

Comment: Опс, прошу прощения, если вы имеете ввиду object parameter, то прошу ссылку на пример.

Comment: Непонятно, как в разметке XAML использовать переменную?

Comment: Не parameter, а values[2]. values[0] и values[1] вы же как-то смогли использовать?

Comment: *Непонятно, как в разметке XAML использовать переменную?* — С помощью Binding

Comment: Подойдет и parameter на самом деле, но это в том случае, если вам не нужно пересчитывать результат в тот момент, когда значение этой переменной меняется. Если надо — надо добавлять привязку к ней как к третьему значению (values[2])

Comment: Спасибо, попробую с Binding. О результататх сообщу завтра вечером.

Comment: Спасибо, используя твои советы передаю переменную в XAML используя DataContext, но все равно не работает. Сможешь подсказать, где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Я думаю у вас неправильные биндинги

Comment: То же так думаю, но если то же самое привязать не к строке а к колонке в конвертер передаются правильные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Вышел из положения конструкцией:

```
private void CanalDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) 
        {
            Canals canal = (Canals)e.Row.DataContext;

            if ((canal.AvWorkDateID == avWorkDateID || canal.AvWorkDateID == null) && canal.AvElCom == null) e.Row.IsEnabled = true;
            else e.Row.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

Хотя непонятно, почему если конвертер привязан к строке, то в **object[] values** поступают значения **Null**, а если конвертер привязан колонке в конвертер передаются правильные значения. Буду разбираться дальше.